# ImportError: "No module named tensorflow" (Keras in Anaconda environment)

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, keras

I have installed Keras and tensorflow using pip in Anaconda environment, but when I run Keras program in tensorflow background it gives error `No module named tensorflow`. Can you please help?

Comment: if you run python in your active environment via the commandline. Can you import tensorflow?

Comment: first I have to activate tensorflow and then run my code to import tensorflow. thank you

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup#anaconda_installation   -->this link says every time I want to use tensorflow.I have to activate tensorflow environment.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but when I moved to anaconda almost 2 years ago, it felt like paradise - no more issues with numpy, mkl, tf, keras... (Compared to vanilla Python, even with Gohlke's libraries - it was a bliss). But now, when we deploy anaconda with cuda, cudnn, tf and keras versions changing from week to week, it's often like the OP described. Then, wait another week, get new packages and everything works again. So try - upgrade everything. If not, downgrade everything. If works: break, else: goto 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your python version and installation command. (`$ conda create -n tensorflow python=<version>`)

If you install tensorflow via conda-forge use:

```
# Linux/Mac OS X, Python 2.7/3.4/3.5, CPU only:
(tensorflow)$ conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

Otherwise, switch the pip command according to the python version like:

```
# Python 2
(tensorflow)$ pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL

# Python 3
(tensorflow)$ pip3 install --ignore-installed --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, please provide more detailed command lines to reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks for the help...actually I reinstalled it by running anaconda as administrator then it started working fine.